# rigidbody bullets UNITY`

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

        lastpos = player.position;
        direction = (lastpos - transform.position).normalized;


        Destroy(gameObject, 4f);

    }
```

get last pos and shoot that direction, collisions dont work this method

````
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(direction * (30f * Time.deltaTime));

    }
``` this dosent work with collisions so i need to use rigidbody forces, any help please? idk how to do that
````

Comment: Are you talking about collision events such as OnCollisionEnter or collisions as in the object should stop moving when it hits something?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to put a rigidbody and a collider (mesh, sphere, capsule, your preference) on the bullet. To move the bullet you can do

```
public float thrust = 1.0f;

void Start() {
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate() {
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
//alternate rb.velocity = new Vector3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

}

void OnCollisionEnter(collision other) {
//do something when the bullet hits another collider
}
```